# How to overwrite the default label generated by the form helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

How can override the default label of cakephp replacing it on my desire label. my **VIEW** code in cakePHP is this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Add');
echo "<h2>Email</h2>"; //Email
echo $this->Form->input('email'); //email
echo $this->Form->submit('submit');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Your Label'));
```